# How to return variables that have been set in MySQL back to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

I have a PHP function which inserts multiple records into MySQL:

```
function commit_purchase($asset_type_ID, $org_ID, $asset_desc, $asset_cost, $date, $org_to_member_ID, $asset_ID, $purchaser_cur_invest, $purchaser_cred_deb, $purchaser_balance) {
    global $db;
    $query = "START TRANSACTION;
          INSERT INTO assets
            (asset_type_ID, org_ID, asset_desc, asset_cost, asset_value, purchase_date, is_approved)
          VALUES
            (:asset_type_ID, :org_ID, :asset_desc, :asset_cost, :asset_cost, :date, 1);
          SET @asset_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
          INSERT INTO cash_out
            (org_to_member_ID, amount, description, date, is_approved, asset_ID)
          VALUES
            (:org_to_member_ID, :asset_cost, :asset_desc, :date, 1, @asset_ID);
          SET @cash_out_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
          INSERT INTO shares
            (asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner, is_approved)
          SELECT assets.asset_ID, pending_asset_shares.member_ID, pending_asset_shares.percent_owner, pending_asset_shares.is_approved
          FROM assets, pending_asset_shares
          WHERE assets.asset_ID = @asset_ID;
          DELETE FROM pending_asset_shares
          WHERE asset_ID = :asset_ID;
          DELETE FROM pending_assets
          WHERE pending_asset_ID = :asset_ID;
          INSERT INTO trans_log
             (translog_id, trans_type, org_to_member_ID, date, purchaser, asset_ID, cur_invest, cash_out_ID, cred_deb, balance)
          VALUES
             (DEFAULT, 3, :org_to_member_ID, :date, :org_to_member_ID, @asset_ID, :purchaser_cur_invest, @cash_out_ID, :purchaser_cred_deb, :purchaser_balance);
          COMMIT;";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_type_ID', $asset_type_ID);
$statement->bindValue(':org_ID', $org_ID);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_desc', $asset_desc);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_cost', $asset_cost);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$statement->bindValue(':org_to_member_ID', $org_to_member_ID);
$statement->bindValue(':purchaser_cur_invest', $purchaser_cur_invest);
$statement->bindValue(':purchaser_cred_deb', $purchaser_cred_deb);
$statement->bindValue(':purchaser_balance', $purchaser_balance);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_ID', $asset_ID);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
return $asset_ID;
```

I am trying to use the first INSERT statment's LAST_INSERT_ID (@asset) as a variable for my next function. The way I am calling the above function, in hopes of setting the variable, is:

```
$asset_ID = commit_purchase($asset_type_ID, $org_ID,.......etc.)
```

I am pretty sure my problem is somewhere around the "return $asset_ID" in my SQL statement. I have been able to do this successfully when using only 1 LAST_INSERT_ID call.

Nothing is being returned at all.

Comment: Don't do so many queries at once!  You should have a separate statement for each query.

Comment: I would love to split these up but it is extremely important that they either all work or fail together. I need them in a transaction. Anyway to split them up while keeping them in a transaction?

Comment: Absolutely.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: that will save me a ton of work, thank you. However, for now, I still need the $asset variable returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as mentioned in my comments, you can use `beginTransaction` to break this up.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Once you have done that, it's just a matter of getting the last inserted ID.  You can use `lastInsertId` for that:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down into multiple queries would really be the best solution, but to answer your original question: If you want to get the value of MySQL variables in PHP, just execute a SELECT query:

```
$asset_ID = mysql_result( mysql_query( 'SELECT @asset_ID' ) );
```

Comment: I placed the command you suggested right below my COMMIT;"; line but i'm still not getting anything back.

Comment: In the same gigantic query?  I'm surprised that works at all, because I thought that PHP's mysql interface ignored everything after the first semicolon anyway (to mitigate injection attacks). Perhaps it  returns the result of the first query (i.e. "START TRANSACTION", which doesn't actually return anything).